# Windows 10 Hyper V connecting to Wifi and Lan

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm trying to set up a hyper-v virtual machine to connect to a corporate LAN via ethernet and internet via Wifi. My windows 10 host machine quite happily connects to wifi and ethernet at the same time. But I can only share either the wifi or the ethernet with the virtual machine. Is there a way to configure Hyper-V to connect to both at the same time?

Comment: Why do you need to share both the WiFi and Ethernet with the machine?

Comment: Your host can connect to both because it has 2 network cards.  If you want to do the same with the VM, add a second NIC and connect it to the other host NIC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create x2 Virtual switches in the Hyper V Virtual Switch Manager, and bind one switch to the Physical Wifi adapter of the host machine, and then bind the other switch to the physical network adapter of the physical host

Once you have created the virtual switches, you should create x2 virtual network adapters for the virtual machine in question and then bind each of those virtual adapters to the newly created virtual switches

e.g virtual NIC 1 is attached to Virtual Switch 1 (Wifi) and then virtual NIC 2 is attached to Virtual Switch 2 (Ethernet)

Comment: I've created the virtual switches however when looking at the settings for the vm i can only select a single virtual switch there is no option to add a second network to the the vm. Is this a limitation as my host machine is running windows 10 not server?

Comment: Have you created a second Virtual Network Adapter for the VM? You can achieve this by opening up the settings for the VM inside the hyper v manager, you then choose add hardware, select network adapter and then add. Once the adapter has been added, under the hadware section of the VM you should see a second network adapter that you can use.

Is it possible to add a screenshot of your VM settings?

Comment: I just found the answer and your last comment confirms it. I'm kicking myself. When looking at the VM settings in Hyper-V I was focusing on the network adaptor heading, if I'd only glanced at the very top of the settings list the very first item is "Add hardware" which obviously lets me add the second NIC to the VM. User not read manual moment. Thanks. Answer accepted.

Comment: You're welcome. I only know how to fix it because I have has the same issues before when creating virtual labs.